# How to write Codable if array of dictionary missing one key

Tags: ios, swift, struct, codable, decodable

With in Server response sometimes missing "tags" key. How we have to write codable struct for this response.

```
[
  {
    "product_id": 10
    "product_name": "Bulb"
    "tags": ["x", "y", "z"]
  },
  {
    "product_id": 11
    "product_name": "Wire"
  }
]
```

decoding like this

```
do {

    // decoding...
    let product_model = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProductItem].self, from: data)

} catch let error {

    print("Product list error(decoder): \(error.localizedDescription)") 
}
```

// Product structure

```
struct ProductItem: Codable {

    // variables
    let product_id: String?
    let product_name: String?
    let tags: [String]?

    // alternative keys...
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case product_id
        case product_name
        case tags // what i have to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste json [here](http://www.jsoncafe.com/) and select **SWIFT CODABLE** in code template. It will generate codable struct for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dahiya_boy thank you. This below code working fine.

```
struct ProductItem : Codable {

        let productId : Int?
        let productName : String?
        let tags : [String]?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case productId = "product_id"
                case productName = "product_name"
                case tags = "tags"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                productId = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .productId)
                productName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .productName)
                tags = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .tags)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you JSON is not correct. It should look similar to this one:

```
[
  {
    "product_id": 10,
    "product_name": "Bulb",
    "tags": ["x", "y", "z"]
  },
  {
    "product_id": 11,
    "product_name": "Wire"
  }
]
```

and for that, your structure should be similar to:

```
struct ProductItem: Codable {

    // variables
    let product_id: Int
    let product_name: String
    let tags: [String]?
}
```

You don't have to provide `CodingKeys` if your variables in the structure are named the same as keys in JSON object. Also, keep in mind that `"product_id": 10,` is a number so you should use `Int` not a `String`.

Comment: Yes correct "CodingKeys" no need. But based on the products json coming like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is missing some commas, the correct JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "product_id": 10,
        "product_name": "Bulb",
        "tags": ["x", "y", "z"]
    },
    {
        "product_id": 11,
        "product_name": "Wire"
    }
]
```

The `product_id` in your code is a `String`, whereas in your JSON, it is a number.

Swift can actually handle missing keys like this, as long as you make the property optional, which you have correctly done here. `tags` will be assigned `nil` when there is no key in the JSON. So you don't really have to do anything other than changing `product_id` to be a `Int`.

Your property names can also be renamed to be more Swifty if you use `convertFromSnakeCase` option when decoding:

```
struct ProductItem: Codable {

    let productId: Int?
    let productName: String?
    let tags: [String]?
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let decoded = try! decoder.decode([ProductItem].self, from: data)
print(decoded[1].tags) // nil
```

Comment: You can write the code even *more Swifty* by removing the CodingKeys and adding the `.convertFromSnakeCase` strategy 

Comment: if all keys coming correctly, this is correct. if tags key missing in few products. what we have to do.

Comment: @KondaYadav It doesn't matter. You don't have to do anything. `ProductItem.tags` will simply be `nil`. It won't crash. Do you want to assign it a default value?

Comment: @Sweeper  I'm getting like this ERROR: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: @KondaYadav Ah that's because your JSON is still invalid. I thought you fixed it in your edit, but the JSON still seems to be missing some commas. You need to somehow fix your server then.

Comment: @Sweeper json is correct. if any key is missing. how we have to take key in codable.

Comment: @KondaYadav You don't have to do anything. If the key `tags` is missing in the JSON, the property `tags` will be `nil` when decoded. This is done by Swift automatically. Do you want to provide a default value?

Comment: @KondaYadav See this [demo](https://repl.it/repls/WavyInsistentSystemadministrator). `tags` will be nil.

Comment: @Sweeper if key is missing its showing The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format Error. Its not decoding. if all key available in each product. I'm getting array of ProductItem.

Comment: @KondaYadav **Never** print `error.localizedDescription` when catching a `DecodingError`, just print `error`. It shows you exactly what's wrong. And omit `let error`, the `error` variable is provided implicitly.

Comment: But i want to display all product. if tags is available display tags. otherwise don't display the tags